# Implications of Gaps in Server-Side Events

Tags: sinatra, server-sent-events

I noticed that on chrome EventSource seems to fire the text-stream every 1.5 or so minutes. I was implementing a pubsub using this in Sinatra and am a bit worried about what will happen in the space between fires. Is there something in the protocol that helps with this?

Comment: What do you mean by "fire"? Do you mean the socket closes and Chrome auto-reconnects for you?

Comment: @DarrenCook yup, that seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your own keep-alives to your data feed. You can either do this regularly every N seconds, or only after N seconds of silence; basically whichever is easier for you to code. Then the keep-alive can either be as simple as an SSE comment (a colon then a couple of LFs), or actual data.

The standard mentions N could be 15 seconds; that is probably more frequent than it needs to be. If you are noticing closes after 90 seconds, then try N=60?

The alternative is to find out which component is dropping the socket and configure it to not do that. (It is unlikely to be Chrome: though if Firefox and other browsers do not have the same behaviour then something interesting is going on.)